# product_type_data not working in List Page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using the following codes in list page which has been written in details page to display the configurable product. But the issue is the bellow codes are not working in list.phtml page.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try the code like this on list page.

```
<?php echo $_product->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
<?php echo $_product->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
<?php echo $_product->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
<?php echo $_product->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: Do you load product before this code?

Comment: Yes. i did.. but still the same thing is displaying.